# Group items by field in array

Tags: php, json, rest, kohana

```
[
            {
                "type": "photo",
                "username": "Зубр Зубров",
                "user_id": "816",
                "avatar": "images/eb/ebffefae4de882a26e02d78f5c493477",
                "date_from": "2014-09-03 12:22:50",
                "comments_count": 0,
                "image": "images/e6/e6069bfcf0beb79100789ffc458c7ff0",
                "image_id": "5924",
                "likes_count": 0,
                "is_liked": false
            },

            {
                "type": "photo",
                "username": "Зубр Зубров",
                "user_id": "816",
                "avatar": "images/eb/ebffefae4de882a26e02d78f5c493477",
                "date_from": "2014-09-03 12:19:15",
                "comments_count": 0,
                "image": "images/37/37c544d487727b8b6a5d199980fd55e2",
                "image_id": "5923",
                "likes_count": 0,
                "is_liked": false
            },
            {
                "type": "photo",
                "username": "Eugene",
                "user_id": "574",
                "avatar": "images/b1/b1722a365c2397d30217ca2cdaefc745",
                "date_from": "2014-09-02 21:10:19",
                "comments_count": 1,
                "image": "images/d4/d471840fa2391268cbff66b568a5d214",
                "image_id": "5922",
                "likes_count": 1,
                "is_liked": true
            }
        ]
```

Above response, is the json which I generate from the server. I have to group items, which date_from field is in 1 hour or less interval with another ones. In above case first two items should be grouped, cause date_from interval between them is nearly 3 mins. Maybe I should make it on sql level, but now the goal is to make it in php code.
Groupping result should output subarray with groupped items

Comment: Could you add any solution attempts? ANY useful CODE?

Comment: Have you tried anything to do this?

Comment: @HAL9000 I wasted 3-4 hours and didn't get any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for grouping it's good idea to use O(1) hash. So you should iterate through the array and setup a new hashing array with "2014-09-03 12" part of the string as key, and an array as value. Add to that array all you need.

I wrote php very long time ago, but in python it would look alike:

```
grouping = {}  # hashing array
for elem in elements:
    grouping_key = elem["date_from"].split(':')[0] # or if you are sure about format: elem["date_from"][:13] - the first 13 characters
    if grouping_key not in grouping.keys():
        grouping[grouping_key]= [] # new array
    grouping[grouping_key].append(elem)
```

now you should have 2 groups.